# Como INSERTAR Cabecera y Detalla en una factura Utilizando Transacction?

Tags: c#, sql

Amigos tengo dos SP, uno inserta la cabecera de la factura, el segundo el detalle, estoy utilizando `TRANSACTION`, mi problema y duda es que si inserto la cabecera y el código pasa bien, pero en el código del sp detalle de factura, ocurre un error, como deshago la cabecera ya que se ejecuto primero, mi pregunta cual es la mejor manera de grabar estos dos registros, ejemplo de mi código actual:

```
SP_INSERTA_FACURA CABECERA
  
  @numerofactura

BEGIN
  --- Iniciar el proceso transaccional de SQLServer
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
      --- Validar si se da un error en el proceso de inserccion
      BEGIN TRY
      ---  Consulta SQL

    Lineas de codigo de la cabecera de fatura
        
  
      --- Confirmar las transacciones o los insert
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
  END TRY
      -- Capturar la expecion
      BEGIN CATCH
      --- Capturando los mensajes de error
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS errNumber
              , ERROR_SEVERITY() AS errState
              , ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS errProcedure
              , ERROR_LINE() AS errLine
              , ERROR_MESSAGE() AS errMessage
            --- Se cancela todas las transacciones o Insert por el error y se desahace el proceso
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION            
    END CATCH   
END
```

Tengo un segundo SP_INSERTA_FACURA_DETALLE

Si ves ellos se ejecutan, pero si pasa el primero y el segundo da error, pierdo el primer registro, si se ejecuta el siguiente código para ejemplo:

Como puedo trabajar este código en uno solo y siempre utilizando los controles de devexpress.

Comment: Creo que estás planteando mal el problema, la operación atómica debería ser la de la factura completa, por lo que abrirías una transacción, insertas la cabecera , insertas el detalle y si todo funciono, comiteas, en caso de cualquier error un rollback

Comment: Asi es Patricio quiero mandar la factura y controlar el insert, por el momento lo tengo separado a como lo presento, quiero llegar mejorando ese codigo a tu recomendacion, pero no estoy claro de como hacerlo correctemente. Si me das una mano a lo que menciona.

Comment: Si lo quieres resolver mediante varios Sps, simplemente quita las transacciones en los que ya tienes, crea un sp base SP_INSERTA_FACURA , que este se encargue de abrir la transacción, y vas llamando dentro de un TRY/CATCH a SP_INSERTA_FACURA_CABECERA, y luego a SP_INSERTA_FACURA_DETALLE, por último comiteas la transacción. Si los Sps tienen errores controlados, deberías retornar un valor y también controlarlo en SP_INSERTA_FACURA por si correspondería hacer también un rollback.

Comment: Si te entiendo, seria capturar el error con el begin catch que ya tengo en cada uno de ellos y devolverlo al SP principal y el comiit y rollback lo haria de una en el SP principal, lo armare si es asi a como te entendi.
Saludos